# How to Add Labels to Confluence Page via REST

Tags: json, tags, label, confluence-rest-api

I've been hunting for the correct way to add labels to a confluence page via REST (tags, categories, or whatever they are calling them today)

the documentation simply says "add json to the body" and then shows this example

```
[{"prefix":"global","name":"label1"},{"prefix":"global","name":"label2"}]
```

Has anyone successfully done this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **POST** the JSON body using this endpoint: POST **/rest/api/content/{id}/label** where the **id** is the id for the content (page).

Reference: https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content/{id}/label-addLabels

*For example:*

POST /rest/api/content/{id}/label HTTP/1.1

Host: yourinstance.atlassian.net

Authorization: Basic YaRtsWdg4VzdAzazhib2FyZA==

Content-Type: application/json

Cache-Control: no-cache

[
    {
        "prefix": "global",
        "name": "label1"
    },
    {
        "prefix": "global",
        "name": "label2"
    }
]

Comment: Just as a follow up my issue was there was a space between the last backslash and the json that I wasn't seeing - I wish there was a validation for confluence rest command strings